# Checking whether user is logged in using React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, passport.js

I am very new to React JS. I am using React starter kit for developing an application. Following is my routes.js

```
/*! React Starter Kit | MIT License | http://www.reactstarterkit.com/ */
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-routing/src/Router';
import http from './core/HttpClient';
import App from './components/App';
import Login from './components/Login';
import SearchPage from './components/SearchPage';

const router = new Router(on => {
    on('*', async (state, next) => { 
       const component = await next();
       return component && <App context={state.context}>{component}</App>
    });

    on('/', async () => <Login />);  
    on('/login', async () => <Login />);        
    on('/search', async () => <SearchPage />);

    on('*', async (state) => {
    const content = await http.get(`/api   /content?path=${state.path}`);
    return content && <ContentPage {...content} />;
    });

    on('error', (state, error) => state.statusCode === 404 ?
    <App context={state.context} error={error}><NotFoundPage /></App> :
    <App context={state.context} error={error}><ErrorPage /></App>
    );
});

export default router;
```

Now I want to use passport.js for the authentication part. I want to redirect to /search only if a valid user is logged in (say username: admin, passsword: admin).
I tried to include the following code snippet which I have used with an old JQuery application to routes.js

```
import passport from 'passport';
import LocalStrategy from 'passport-local';
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
 done(null, user);
});
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
 usernameField: 'employeeNumber',
 passwordField: 'password'
},
function(username, password, done) {
 if(username === "admin" && password === "admin"){
  var user={"Name":"Admin"}; 
  return done(null, user);
 }
 else{
  return done(null, false); 
 }
}
));
```

I am not able to proceed how to implement this in my routes.js.
I don't want to use Flux.
Is there any possible way to implement passport.js in my application?
Am I trying to implement it in a correct way?

Please give me suggestions. Thanks in advance.